# (Retool) query: Failed to upload. This might be due to a CORS issue on the bucket, so please double check that your CORS settings are correct

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-shell, retool

I failed to upload a file to **Cloud Storage** on **GCP** from **Retool** many times and always got the error below:

[image]

> query: Failed to upload. This might be due to a CORS issue on the
> bucket, so please double check that your CORS settings are correct.

Actually, I made **cors.json** with the command below on **Cloud Shell**:

```
vi cors.json
```

Then, wrote the code below to **cors.json**:

```js
[
  {
    "origin": ["https://myorigin.retool.com"],
    "method": ["*"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

Finally, set **cors.json** for **my bucket** in **Cloud Storage, GCP** running the command below:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://mybucket-bc123.appspot.com
```

In addition, the **access control** of the bucket is **"Fine-grained"**.

[image]

Are there any solutions to upload a file to **Cloud Storage** on **GCP** from **Retool**?

Comment: I am not familiar with retool.com. Is the error reported in the user's browser by a script running in the browser or at a backend server running (hosted on) retool.com?

Comment: Yes, the error is reported in the user's browser by a script running in the browser on Retool. It should be the original error of Retool.

Comment: This is either an authorization or CORS problem. What form of authorization are you using? Try wildcarding the CORS origin to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I don't know what authorization I'm using but I will try your idea which is wildcarding the CORS origin.

Comment: Is the Cloud Storage bucket public or private?

Comment: It's public. The problem should be "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"]. I will change it to "responseHeader": ["*"] and try.

Comment: I hope you are aware that having a bucket public is very dangerous. Make the bucket private as soon as possible. Then you will need to implement signed URLs to support upload requests. Do not assume that CORS will protect your bucket - it does not. Only the browser enforces CORS. I can easily write an app that ignores CORS.

Comment: Check if adding `x-goog-acl` inside `responseHeader` will fix the issue. Have you seen this [thread](https://community.retool.com/t/intermittent-cors-issue-when-uploading-files-to-google-cloud-storage/3949)?

Comment: I changed the access control of the bucket from "Fine-grained" to "Uniform" and finally, I could upload my file. Thanks a lot. In addition, if the access control of the bucket is "Fine-grained", we need to use "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "x-goog-acl"] instead of "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **"x-goog-acl"** to **"responseHeader"** for the **access control** of the bucket **"Fine-grained"**:

```js
[
  {
    "origin": ["https://myorigin.retool.com"],
    "method": ["*"],                
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "x-goog-acl"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600           // ↑↑↑ Here ↑↑↑
  }
]
```

In addition, if the **access control** of the bucket is **"Uniform"**:

[image]

**"x-goog-acl"** is not needed:

```js
[
  {
    "origin": ["https://myorigin.retool.com"],
    "method": ["*"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```